# Javascript get key from an object inside an array which store on a index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object with key value pairs inside an array:

```
error : [ { firstName : true },
          { lastName : false },
          { email : true }
        ]
```

I want to fetch the key from objects.

I tried this, but this will show undefined in output

```
let result = error.map((row, index) => { 
          console.log("key" + row[0] + " index " + index);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys`:

```js
 

const obj = {
error : [ { firstName : true },
      { lastName : false },
      { email : true }
    ]
}

const keys = obj.error.flatMap(Object.keys);

console.log(keys);
```

You may need this for an older browser:

```js
 

const obj = {
error : [ { firstName : true },
      { lastName : false },
      { email : true }
    ]
}

const keys = obj.error.map(Object.keys).reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr));

console.log(keys);
```

Comment: Does not work in chrome `Uncaught TypeError: obj.error.flatMap is not a function`

Comment: Whoops @AnkitAgarwal, polyfill required, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Fixed @AnkitAgarwal, any better?

Comment: Now this answer is very complex and heavy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` with `Object.keys()`:

```js
var data = {
  error: [{
      firstName: true
    },
    {
      lastName: false
    },
    {
      email: true
    }
  ]
};
var keys = data.error.map(e => Object.keys(e)[0]);;
console.log(keys);
```

Or use `forEach()` with spread syntax:

```js
var data = {
  error: [{
      firstName: true,
      address: false
    },
    {
      lastName: false
    },
    {
      email: true
    }
  ]
};
var keys = [];
data.error.forEach(e => keys = [...keys, ...Object.keys(e)]);;
console.log(keys);
```

Comment: What if there's more than one property in each object?

Comment: @JackBashford The second snippet works, spread syntax.